# jQuery loop and reset custom css animation

Tags: jquery, css, setinterval, css-animations

I have an animated banner witch it should restart the animation when it's done, my problem is the banner animated only once. 
This my jQuery code I use:

```
FourshatiAnimation();

function FourshatiAnimation() {
/* One */
$forshati_text.addClass('forshati-text-trans');

$forshati_logo.delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass('forshati-logo-trans');
});

$download_btn.delay(2000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass('dwn-btn-trans');
});

$forshati_one.delay(4500).fadeOut('slow');


/* Two */
$icon_two.delay(5000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).addClass('icon-img-trans');
    next(); 
    $text_two.delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass('forshati-txt-trans');
    });

    $forshati_text.removeClass('forshati-text-trans');
    $forshati_logo.removeClass('forshati-logo-trans');
    $download_btn.removeClass('dwn-btn-trans');
});

$forshati_two.delay(9000).fadeOut('slow');
$icon_two.removeClass('icon-img-trans');
$text_two.removeClass('forshati-txt-trans');
window.setTimeout(function() { FourshatiAnimation() }, 10000)
}
```

[my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaLJ5/1/).

Comment: Is the console showing any errors?

Comment: @James Sadly no, only the animation is not repeating it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have made a demo of the work ---> [HERE](http://www.mytintshop.com/testing/)

You can view page source to copy the css, and tweak. I have explained below.

I am using `keyframes` to run the animations. They are not complete supported, but neither are regular css animations.

You may have to adjust the positions and timing to get it perfect.
This is an example below of the key frame. It is creating an animation by the name `item1` and setting properties based on how far through the animation.

```
@keyframes item1{
    0%   {opacity: 1; left: -200px;}
    15%  {opacity: 1: left: 200px;}
    50%  {opacity: 0; left: 200px;}
    100% {opacity: 0; left: -200px;}
}
```

You trigger the animation like below: Calls the name `item1` of the animation, the duration, and then tells it to repeat.

```
.forshati-text{
          animation: item1 10s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: item1 10s infinite;
}
```

When you see the CSS. I have put `@keyframes` first.
There are four vendor prefixes for each `@keyframes`. So be careful if you tweak it, make sure you change all four for the same animation name. ex. `item1`

```
@keyframes
@-webkit-keyframes
@-moz-keyframes
@-o-keyframes
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that, but unfortunately I don't know to make the code run synchronize. live example is now included in my question.

Comment: By the way I looked at this [suggestion](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @BilalKhoukhi here is an updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jafrisella/qaLJ5/2/)  it doesn't completely work. But the problem is the `.fadeOut()` because you are not fading back in. There are other problems but that is step one

Comment: I already tried that solution but unfortunately it didn't work. Can you suggest a completely different way to do it? Thank you

Comment: @BilalKhoukhi yes, but it will be some time tomorrow before i can get to it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it. and take your time, there is no rush, I already gave my client a GIF image to use for the ad until I prepare the code.

Comment: @BilalKhoukhi ok i have changed my answer above to show the work. Just follow the link provided to copy code.